# Passing a unique class to a rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render @users with different classes from different views. Trying to pass a class as a string into the partial:

```
<%= render @users, :locals=>{:style=> "col-sm-2 col-xs-12"} %>
```

And then in the partial:

```
<div class="<%= style %>">
```

But this is giving an error:

undefined local variable or method `style'

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you write it as: `<%= render @users, style: "col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>`

If you use `:locals`, you can't use the shorthand method and would have to write out the entire render call like the [docs say](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) and would look like `<%= render partial: "users", locals: { users: @users, style: "col-sm-2 col-xs-12" } %>`.